# Calculating the minimum s,t-cut in a graph with parallel and antiparallel arcs in C++ using boost

Tags: c++, optimization, graph, boost, max-flow

I would like to calculate the minimum s,t-cut in a directed graph, having parallel and antiparallel arcs. I tried to calculate the minimum s,t-cut using boost by first calculating a maximum flow. I stumbled across boost::push_relabel_max_flow. However, i quickly realized, that it is not able to handle parallel and anti-parallel arcs in the graph.

I tried a lot of the other max-flow algorithms from the boost library (e.g. boost::boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow or boost::kolmogorov_max_flow). Unfortunately no algorithm could handle parallel or anti-parallel arcs. Could you suggest another library which is able to handle such graphs or ways of solving this issue (maybe i missed something).

Comment: You can substitute the anti-parallel edge by introducing a new node halfway the edge, with the same capacity from and to this new node.

Comment: Thank you for this awesome suggestion! This sounds really good! I will try it immediately :-D

Comment: Somehow I'm reminded of this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/77105714/85371 - I don't know how, it seems like a fuzzy match, but just in case you can connect the dots that I cannot, here's the link :)